# Why are medial epicondylopathies more effectively treated with open, traditional surgical procedures than with arthroscopies?

Tags: tendons, epicondylitis

I read on http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00646 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170320161714/http://orthoinfo.aaos.org/topic.cfm?topic=A00646)):

> Common arthroscopic procedures include: Treatment of tennis elbow (lateral epicondylitis)
>
> There are several elbow surgical treatments that are currently most effective when done as an open, traditional procedure. These include surgeries to: Treat golfer's elbow (medial epicondylitis)

Why are medial epicondylopathies more effectively treated with  open, traditional surgical procedures than with arthroscopies, whereas it isn't the case for lateral epicondylopathies?